# What was the original Barrayaran plan for the Komarr invasion

Tags: character-motivation, vorkosigan-saga

In *The Warrior's Apprentice*, Aral Vorkosigan is described by the highly competent Tung as producing

> the most complex strategy laid out logically as a wiring diagram—politics, economics, and all—I swear the man's mind must operate in five dimensions.

and

> Seemed like every natural weak point in mercenary-employer relations
> got blown up in our faces—and that was before the first shot was even
> fired. Vorkosigan's intelligence pathfinders at work, we learned
> later."

But the Komarr invasion ended in an expensive occupation, resulting in repeated bloody revolts. Part of this is due to the Solstice massacre in which Aral's political officer directed the murder of many civilians.  But it seems to me that Aral is too smart (and politically astute as noted by Tung) to plan on a long-term occupation at all.

**Is there any canonical statement about what the original plan for Komarr was?**

I'd like to think that the original plan was a conquest of the planet intended to force a negotiated authorized Barrayaran presence in Komarr space, guarding the transfer points (since the security of the transfer points to Barrayar was the strategic need that Barrayar has), but I know of no evidence to that effect.

Comment: "All skill is in vain when an angel pees in the touchhole of your musket."  I think the plan just couldn't survive the human elements working outside it.

Comment: No question that the plan failed in part - but what was the plan?  Occupation forever but on good terms seems too foolish a goal to try for (at least for Aral)

Comment: [Posted where Lois might reply to it](https://baensbar.net/index.php?t=msg&goto=2173747&#msg_2173747)

Comment: Thank you for that